# Whenever i try to install pip package for python3 using pip3 it gives a long error

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, linux-mint

Linux mint 
I'm having trouble install python3 packages using pip3 
do i need to use "pip install packagename" i think normal pip install's for python2 and pip3 for python3
sudo pip3 install pyinstaller or sudo pip3 install pyodbc

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-7b88du29/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (39 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  Error in sys.excepthook:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
      if not enabled():
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

  Original exception was:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-7b88du29/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python3.x installed ? If yes, try to use latest one, for example `python3.8 -m pip module-to-install`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+IntFlag

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

and then carry on with your installation commands.

Mark this answer correct if your problem is solved.

Thanks